# UnityAPP FIle Upload Using online PHP and ftp method

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, ftp

I am trying to upload an image file through my develop unity app, using php code with an ftp method.
when im using the localphp file i can upload successfully but whne i upload it unto 000webhost and try to run is giving me this error

```
Warning:  ftp_put(C:\Users\fravi\Downloads/bobo.gif): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd2/455/18681455/public_html/php/phpUploads/upSingleFile.php on line 18

Notice:  Undefined variable: filenamez in /storage/ssd2/455/18681455/public_html/php/phpUploads/upSingleFile.php on line 22
There was an error uploading
```

This is my php code

```php
    <?php
    
    require_once 'config.php';
    
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    $filepath = $_POST['directory'];
    
    $ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_host) or die ("Couldnt Connect to $ftp_host");
    
    ftp_login($ftp_connection, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass) or die ("Couldnt Login to ftp server");
    
    ftp_pasv($ftp_connection, true);
    
    $local_dir = "$filepath";
    $remote_server_dir = "/public_html/files/profileimg";
    
    
    if(ftp_put($ftp_connection, "$remote_server_dir/$filename", "$local_dir/$filename", FTP_BINARY))
    {
        echo "Successfully Uploaded $filename";
    }else{
        echo "There was an error uploading $filenamez";
    }
    
    ftp_close($ftp_connection);
    ?>
```

I can fetch the filename and directory of the file successfully.

Comment: Windows(\`\\`) & Linux(`/`) use different directory separators.

Comment: For the second error, looks like filenamez was a typo?